# PHP: Require a file with prices

Tags: php, html, class, include, require

I am implementing a small online purchase page with a very few products.

```
<?php  
$item_name = "lamp";
$item_price = 29.99;
$item_category = "furniture";
$item_Dollar = 29;
$item_Cents = 99;
?>
```

How do I go about it? It's only 2 product types and basically only prices would differ so there is no need for a database. I was thinking of including a .php file containing all the prices and having a function there that will `switch($id)` between them and reassign the values.

```
<?php
    function selectProduct($id) {

     switch($id) {
          case 1:
              $item_name = "lamp";
              $item_price = 19.99;
              $item_category = "furniture";
              $item_Dollar = 19;
              $item_Cents = 99;
              break;

          case 2:
              // and so on...

          default: break;
     }
    }
?>
```

The logic enters the respective cases but it does not reassign the instance variables. For some reason when I try to access them on another page after `require_once(pricings.php);` they are empty. I am not very familiar with PHP which probably made itself obvious from the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) -- variables you define in a function are not available outside that function.

Comment: Fair enough. Then how do I set the variables from within the function?

Comment: your variables are in local scope to function . `$item_name` is local .to use vars declare outside function use `global` keyword like so `global $item_name;`

Comment: Clarification -- you need to learn about scope in order to better understand how PHP works, but I certainly do not mean to imply that you should simply declare everything as global. That's bad practice. If you use a function, it should return its work, not set it in a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build an array of items, where each element is a key/value pair, the key being the item id and the value being another array of key/value pairs for the item's attributes:

```
$items = array(
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'lamp',
        'price' => '19.99',
        'category' => 'furniture',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'chair',
        'price' => '29.99',
        'category' => 'furniture',
    ),
);
```

Then you can simply refer to the array by using its product id as the index:

```
$id = 1;
echo "Name is: " . $items[$id]['name'];
echo "Price is: " . $items[$id]['price'];
```

Comment: You just beat me! Much simpler approach than setting values every time. Actually, nvm, I think I've got you beat!

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. I really liked this approach. It works like a charm.

Comment: Ah, too slow, I was.  I think interacting with it as an array is spot on, but storing it as `json` would make it more portable and easier to update, as outputting the json to a flat file is nicer than outputting  an array (that is not serialized, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would forget about functionizing your data and just use an array. Thats what there for. also this will make it much easier to port your data to a database in the future.

```
<?php 
$products = array(
    array('item_name'=>'lamp', 'item_price'=>19.99, 'item_category'=>'furniture', 'item_dollar'=>19, 'item_cents'=>99),
    array('item_name'=>'chair', 'item_price'=>19.99, 'item_category'=>'furniture', 'item_dollar'=>19, 'item_cents'=>99),
);
//
echo $products[0]['item_name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store your items as a JSON object, which can easily be transformed to a native php array, and also would allow a straightforward approach to updating and adding items as needed. I won't get into those benefits here, but the items could be stored as:

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "lamp",
    "price": "19.99",
    "category": "furniture"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "chair",
    "price": "29.99",
    "category": "furniture"
  }
}
```

In a file such as `items.json` and when needing to interact with it, convert it to native php:

```
$items_json = file_get_contents('items.json');
$items = json_decode($items_json, true);
```

Then as Alex has shown, you can interact with your item list like so:

```
$id = 1;
echo "Name is: " . $items[$id]['name'];
echo "Price is: " . $items[$id]['price'];
```

Answer (score -1):

To change variables scope, add global keyword and list all global variables, try:

```
function selectProduct($id) {
  global $item_name, $item_price, $item_category, $item_Dollar, $item_Cents;
```

but it's not good practise. imho, you should wrap data into object, and return objects, ie:

```
function selectProduct($id) {
  $item = new StdClass;
  //...
  switch($id) {
    case 1: $item->name = "name";
            //...
            break;
    //...
  }
  return $item;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array_to_use = array();  
$array_to_use['item_name'] =  $item_name = "lamp";
 $array_to_use['item_price'] = $item_price = 29.99;
 $array_to_use['item_category'] = $item_category = "furniture";
 $array_to_use['item_Dollar'] = $item_Dollar = 29;
$array_to_use['item_Cents'] =  $item_Cents = 99;
?>

<?php
    function selectProduct($id) {
    global $array_to_use; 
   extract($array_to_use); 
     switch($id) {
          case 1:
              $item_name = "lamp";
              $item_price = 19.99;
              $item_category = "furniture";
              $item_Dollar = 19;
              $item_Cents = 99;
              break;

          case 2:
              // and so on...

          default: break;
     }
    }
?>
```

Updated Should work .